# Are *_r UNIX calls reentrant (async-signal safe), thread safe or both?

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, concurrency, call

There is a difference in re-entrant and thread-safe functions and I don't know if Linux functions ending with _r are thread-safe, re-entrant (I mean async-signal safe) or both,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are thread-safe.

[Stevens/Rago APUE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739) teaches the distinction between thread-safe functions (reentrant with respect to being called by multiple threads), and async-signal-safe functions (reentrant with respect to signal handlers, so can be called safely from within a signal handler).

APUE ch 12.5 *Reentrancy* lists ~79 functions which are not thread-safe, then ~11 have equivalents which *are* reentrant, those are the *_r functions. That means those 11 can be called by multiple threads at the same time.

APUE ch 10.6 *Reentrant Functions* lists ~135 functions which are async-signal-safe. They block signal delivery when needed. So, you can use them in signal handler code. Note, async-signal-safeness only matters when functions are called inside a signal handler. That may motivate one to not write signal handler code, as further details are tricky.

[Kerrisk TLPI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272200) ch 21 *Signals: Signal Handlers* has its own table of functions which are async-signal-safe. Interestingly it is not quite same as APUE.

None of the *._r are listed as async-signal-safe by either of these references.

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity in regard to term reentrant function.

Comment: Which of these definitins of reentrant function is true?
1.APUE differs functions as reentrant in threads (thread safe) and reentrant in signal handlers (async-signal safe)
2.Wikipedia:reentrant function is the one which can be interrupted in the middle of its execution and then safely called again before its previous invocation's complete(async-signal safe)
3. SUSv3(TLPI p.423): f.whose effect, when called by two or more threads, is guaranteed to be as if the threads each executed the function one after the other in an undefined order, even if the actual execution is interleaved(thread-safe)